# How to configure logger to debug level when using jetty-maven-plugin?

Tags: jetty, netbeans-8, maven-jetty-plugin

I would like to see the Spring Security DEBUG log running on my Web Servlet app.

Here is my POM.xml config.

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.eclipse.jetty</groupId>
    <artifactId>jetty-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>9.4.38.v20210224</version>
    <configuration>
        <stopPort>9966</stopPort>
        <stopKey>jetty-stop</stopKey>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

How can I configure this?

Comment: I would have expected that `mvn --debug jetty:run` would be enough.  Do you have spring logging configured specifically in your webapp? (if so, then you'll need to configure the debug logging there)

Comment: --debug is too verbose. I redirected it to a file to analyze later. Then I found out that the debug messages were being sent to the console, which resolved for me. I can't define a solution that way. I did not make any specific log settings.